# Xcode LanchScreenでiPhoneX系とそれ以外でレイアウトを作りたい

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

LanchScreen.storyboardで質問です。

現在AutoLayoutでLanchScreenのレイアウトを作成しています。
iPhone5〜8とiPadのレイアウトに関しては、Size Classを使用して作成しました。
https://dev.classmethod.jp/references/ios8-trait-collection/

ここまでは問題ないのですが、問題はiPhone5〜8とiPhoneX系で別のレイアウトにしたい場合にどうしたらよいか分かりません。
※iPhone5〜8とiPhoneX系ではSize Classの指定方法が同じ為

この場合はどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

単純にナビゲーションバーを描画したLanchScreenを作りたいだけなのですが。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 1枚絵を表示することしか出来ませんが、storyboardではなく、LaunchImageを使えば画面サイズ別の起動時イメージを表示することができます。また「単純にナビゲーションバーを描画したLanchScreenを作りたい」と言うことですが、SafeAreaベースの制約をつければ特に別のレイアウトにする必要はないように思うのですが？すでに作成されたと言うiPhone5〜8のレイアウトの詳細をお示しいただいて、iPhone X系ではどこをどう変えたい、と言うことを明らかにされた方がお望みの回答が得やすいかと思います。

Comment: @OOPer 
コメントありがとうございます。
実現したいことなどを、もっと詳細に書くべきでした。
iPadのマルチタスク機能に対応したい為、LaunchImageではなく、LanchScreenである必要が

Comment: コメントが途中で切れてしまっているんですが、様々な理由でstoryboardを使う必要はあろうかと思います。ご自身の質問は「編集」できますので、どういった画面を実現したいのか追記していただければ、より的確なアドバイスが得やすいかと思います。

Comment: 時間が空いてしまい、恐れ入ります。
storyboardにてNavigaionBarのような帯のある画面を作成したいです。

現状やっているのはLanchScreenの上部にUIViewを配置し、Portraitでは高さ 44の制約、Landscapeでは高さ32の制約を入れてます。

が、 iPhoneX系では問題ないのですが、X以外の端末だと実際のNavigaionBarと高さがズレてしまいます。

iPhoneX系とそれ以外で分ける方法はないでしょうか？
可能で

Comment: あれば制約で解決できるのが良いです。

Comment: 字数に限りのあるコメントでは、あなたのやりたいことが十分伝わってきません。ご自身の質問は編集できるはずですので、ご質問内容を編集して(できれば画像なども交えて)質問に追加の情報を記載してみてください。編集することによりアクティブリストの上位に置かれることになり、より多くの読者にあなたの問題を考えてもらえるようにもなります。

Comment: @OOPer 分かりました、ありがとうございます。